# Why does mounted in Vue plug or in Mixin work several times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

Why does it repeat itself and how to prevent it and make it happen only once ? Is it bug? Here in plugin:

```js
const globala = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.mixin({
      mounted() {
        console.log('hi')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And here in just mixin:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  mounted() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixin can either be global or local to a component.  If you define it [globally](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), it will be applied to every component created afterwards:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  mounted() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
})
```

If you define it [locally](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics), it will only apply to the components where you manually add it:

```js
const myMixin = {
  mounted() {
    console.log('hi')
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mixins: [myMixin] // Only added to this component
});
```

You've defined a global mixin, so every component created afterwards will implement the `mounted` hook.